# how to fix background-image not extending full height of wp template page, with cover and 100% w/h enabled

Tags: css, wordpress

I am creating a custom wp theme, and although on my front-page.php the body background image- which is a gradient -- extends the length of the full page, on the 3 other static pages - about, contact and prices, the gradient only stretches about 500px or so and then starts again.

Everything was fine before I began making it into a wp theme -- which I'm new at -- so I feel there must be something with the page {id}.php config? -- pages are titled - page-about.php etc

My css is as follows:

```
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(140deg, rgba(175, 224, 175, 0.452) 0%, rgba(0, 68, 0, 0.623) 90%);
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was to change

```
height: 100%;
```

to

```
height: auto;
```